# Automatic transmission car reversed in a hill with engine off in reverse gear, now the car won't move

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission

Automatic transmission car reversed in a hill  with engine off in reverse gear, now the car won't move, Can someone explain what's happening ?

engine stopped when i was driving uphill due to low fuel, 
so i put the gear to "R" and slowly reversed the car in down hill with engine state off. 
then i refueled and put gear in "D" and tried to move , but it doesn't move, car tries to go forward but the force is not enough to make the car go forward.

it's a honda fit aria 2003.
a CVT automatic tranmission.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the problem you cannot get the shifter to move out of park?

Comment: How did it reverse with the engine off? Or did it run downhill in reverse and that damaged the box? What happened to the brakes? Foot & emergency? So many details missing.

Comment: Did you put it into reverse with the engine off?  It won't start unless it's in park or neutral...

Comment: updated the question with details. :)

Comment: You confused the hell out of that transmission control module, No power while switching into reverse, then providing power on drive, you should of put it in neutral and went backwards, never drive, reverse when car doesn't have power, I'd start with the fuses then look into the TCM, but it could be the transmission solenoid or shafts too, I had the same problem and the mechanic thought it was the trasmission, but it was just the big crank wheel thing that was cracked, I can't think right now sorry, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get the transmission checked by a competent mechanic, transmission shop or the dealer.

Your best option would have been to have just parked the vehicle and brought fresh fuel to it.

Or,possibly, let it coast in neutral but not in reverse, so you need to get it checked - whatever is wrong is not likely to be simple...